# Is (the type of) String.class a subtype of (the type of) Object.class?

Tags: java, inheritance

In Java, do class objects have the same heritance relations as the classes they represent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.class` property always returns a `Class` object. The `Class` class (weird) has a generic parameter. The generic parameter types are subclasses.

```
Class<String> stringClass = String.class;
Class<Object> objectClass = Object.class;
```

And because with generics, `Type<foo>` is *NOT* a supertype of `Type<subtype_of_foo>` (see [the Java tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)), this means, that the answer is "No".

Comment: No, generic parameter types are NOT subclasses; they're all the same class, due to type erasure, generic parameters don't exist once the compiler has done its thing.

Comment: Thanks for being able to put my thought into words. My brain isn't quite in gear. Time for some brain juice...

Answer (score 4):

`Class` objects in Java are all same Class.

You can tell because if you look at the Javadoc you can see that the [`Class` class is `final`.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is only one class with the name `Class`. String.class is an instanceof Class, as well as Object.class.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
boolean answer = Object.class.isAssignableFrom(String.class);
System.out.println(answer); // true!
```

however:

```
Class<Object> string = String.class; <-- compile-time error
Class<? extends Object> string = String.class; <-- it's ok
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason Class does not extend Class even if Y extends X is that for any generic type G, G does not extend G

You might want to look this up in FAQ etc. A bag of apples is not a bag of fruit, even though apple is a fruit; because you can add any fruit to the latter but only apples to the former.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is not the case. The object that represents class of `java.lang.String`, as well as any other class, is of class `java.lang.Class` always.

Bear in mind that `java.lang.Class` is defined as **final**, so you cannot *subclass* it.

Answer (score 0):

All Class objects are instances of a Class.

If you want to know the hierarchy of a class you can call the getSuperClass() and getInterfaces()

Note: you may need to call these recursively to get all super classes and interfaces.